# Concerning the lower incomplete gamma function

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

$\gamma$ is the lower [incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).
Is $\gamma(1, x) \ge \gamma(k, kx)$ when $k \in Z^+$, $x \in (0,1)$?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Fortuon: I don't know if your question is serious, but I tried some algebra, some calculus, wolfram alpha, and googling for bounds.

Comment: Welcome to Math.Stackexchange! It is often helpful if you list/describe what you have already done, so that potential answerers can see the dead ends you have been in and avoid them.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.emis.de/journals/ZAA/1803/20.html), by any chance?

Comment: @J.M. yes I saw that when I was "googling for bounds" but I was not able to convert it into a solution...

Answer (score 3):

[It doesn't appear to be the case.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+gamma%28k%29-gamma%28k%2Ck+x%29%2Cx%3D0+to+1%2C+k%3D1+to+4)

*Addendum*: Notice that
$\gamma(1,x) = 1-e^{-x}$, so $\gamma(1,x) < 1$ for $x\in(0,1)$.
But
$$\gamma(k,k x) \sim \frac{(k x e^{-x})^k}{k(1-x)}
\qquad (k\to\infty).$$
(See [DLMF 8.11.6](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11#E6).)
Thus, for any $x\in(0,1)$ we can find a $k$ large enough so
$\gamma(k,k x) > 1 > \gamma(1,x)$.